# How to set TAB behavior in Org-mode source-blocks when the language isn't supported?

Tags: org-mode

How can I set a default <kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior (i.e. 4 spaces instead of tab) in an Org source-block when the language **is not** supported? Example:

```
#+begin_src xyz
lkjsdf
    iouqweou  
#+end_src
```

Using TAB within the source-block gives me the following error message:

> org-edit-src-code: No such language mode: xyz-mode

I've already added

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```

to the top of my init-file, and I'm loading org-mode via *use-package*

```
(use-package org
:ensure org-plus-contrib
:mode (("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
:hook
(org-mode . variable-pitch-mode)
(org-mode . visual-line-mode)
:config
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t))
```

Comment: Note: `tab-width` is definitely not what you want to change here.  `C-h o tab-width RET` says "NOTE: This controls the display width of a TAB character, and not
the size of an indentation step."

Comment: By default,  `TAB` is bound to `org-cycle`, which does not give rise to the error you show, so you probably have some customization in place. Check what `TAB` is bound to in your case with `C-h c TAB`. Also, try `emacs -q -l minimal.el` where`minimal.el` is an init file with the bare minimum of initialization needed and see if you can reproduce the problem there: I suspect you will not be able to.

Comment: @NickD When I start Emacs with `emacs -q` `TAB` is bound to `org-cycle`; when I use my own init-file, `TAB` is _also bound_ to `org-cycle` -- so no difference there. And also when starting with `emacs -q` the issue remains the same: If I press `TAB` in a code-block of an unknown language, the cursor won't move.

Comment: That's *different* behavior than what you report in your question: there you report an *error*, not that the cursor does not move. The latter is to be expected, the former not. But how are we to figure out what's happening, if you don't report accurately?

Comment: @NickD sry I wasn't clear:  When I press `TAB` in a code-block of an unknown language, the cursor won't move _and_ I get the aforementioned error-message … and that's not the behavior I want; if I press `TAB` in an source-block of an unknown language, I want that the cursor moves 4 spaces.

Comment: If you can get that error with `-q`, I would suggest that you submit a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. I cannot reproduce it though.

Comment: @NickD what does _your_ tab-key do, if you press it in a code-block of an 'unsupported' language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org-tab-first-hook` hook runs as the first action when TAB is pressed, so you need a function that checks if (1) the point is inside a src block and (2) the language is not found. If both conditions are true, indent to column 4. To insert 4 spaces literally, change the `indent-to` expression to `(insert (make-string 4 ?\s))`.

```el
(add-hook 'org-tab-first-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (org-in-src-block-p t)
              (let* ((elt (org-element-at-point))
                     (lang (intern (org-element-property :language elt)))
                     (langs org-babel-load-languages))
                (unless (alist-get lang langs)
                  (indent-to 4))))))
```